# What are the default values for caretRectForPosition or How to set a BOOL that determines an override of a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

In my `UITextField` subclass I'm using the next code to hide the blinking caret:

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}
```

My goal is to set a property to enable or disable the above. My problem is that I don't know what the default rect is in order to show the caret.

Another option I thought about is to set a bool that determines if to over ride the method `caretRectForPosition` or not. Is that possible?

Comment: How about `CGRect rect = [super caretRectForPosition:position];` ?

Comment: Works! please add it as an answer so I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could just check your flag and return accordingly (a zero rect or the `super` implementation). Something like this:

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return self.isCaretEnabled ? [super caretRectForPosition:position] : CGRectZero;
}
```

Where `isCaretEnabled` is your `BOOL` property of course.